# Can not exit from Heroku Rails Console after running script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using `heroku run rails console` to automate the running of a single-line query. In this case it just prints a sentence with the number of users.

```
> echo "puts \"There are #{User.count} users\"" | heroku run rails console -a my-example-app
Running rails console on ⬢ my-example-app... up, run.7734 (Standard-1X)
puts "There are #{User.count} users"
Loading staging environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)
irb(main):001:0> puts "There are #{User.count} users"
There are 14388 users
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> exit


^C[01:40:30] >
```

The functionality works - it prints the specified count and it dumps me on to the `rails console` live shell.

However, I'm unable to `exit` from that at the end. Notice that I typed `exit` but it doesn't actually exit. I had to kill the process with `CTRL+C` in order to exit out back to my local environment.

I'm curious about -

- Why this happens? (Just trying to learn more about how these processes run)
- How can I get around it?

I also tried

```
echo "puts \"There are #{User.count} users\"; exit"
```

to try auto-exiting at the end, but still no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: That is a bit of a worry ... did you try logging a ticket with Heroku?

Comment: Is the process time consuming or with huge calculations,which is still running behind the scenes....??

Comment: @Milind - Nope, it's not. It's total execution time is under 10 seconds.

Comment: the console says..There are 14388 users..its a good number for default dyno on heroku of 512 MB